# Measuring the effect of sample size on classification

Tags: sample-size, bootstrap, caret

I've got a data frame with 1000 observations and I am playing with classification methods using `caret` package. I'm mostly using the bootstrap method to check model quality.

One of the questions I got is how does the initial sample size affect classification quality. I think I could check this effect by limiting the iterations of bootstrap to sample just 100 or 300 observations instead of 1000 and compare accuracy/kappa variables. Am I right?

If so, how can I do this in `caret`?